# Relations and Categories

Tags: categories, relations

What's given:

```
Channel: Nutrition
Entries Fieldtype: restaurant
Category Fieldtype : menu

Category: Menu

Channel: Menus that also use relations using restaurant field.
```

Each item in the nutrition channel has restaurant and menu category selected.

On a restaurant's menu page I'm trying to list menu items from the nutrition channel grouped by categories.

Currently I use the following snippet

```
            {% for category in craft.categories.group('menu').all() %}
                <h3 id="{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.title }}</h2>
                <ul class="menu-items">
                    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('nutrition').relatedTo(category).orderBy('title').all() %}
                        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
```

Which works fine. However if I add more nutrition items and assign them to another restaurant they'll be listed as well.

I assume we need to define restaurant first

```
{% set restaurant = craft.entries.section('restaurant').one() %}
```

but what are my next steps?

Answer (score 1):

The next step is that you would need to chain `.relatedTo(restaurant)` to your existing `craft.entries()` call

Comment: What would be the final snippet for this? I have problems to make it work.

Comment: Anonyone please?